# How to syndicate a Google+ Feed?

Tags: google-plus

How do I syndicate a specific circle of google+ feed for republishing onto a website?

I am amble to find directions online for how to syndicate to RSS or a Widget the public feed of a Google+ profile -- is there a way yo do this for a specific circle?

Or is the only option to make a dummy Google+ account that received the posts from the primary google+ account via a circle subscription -- and then syndicate that dummy account's public feed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the only way to get activities is list public ones for a specific profile or page. If you would like to list the public activities for several profiles/pages at once you will have to manually compile a list and pragmatically loop through each listing their activities.

You can search for a feature request allowing you to pull activities from profiles/pages in a circle in the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/list) or create one if none is found.